# catch "NVIDIA OpenGL driver lost connection" error

Tags: c++, opengl

I am developing an application in C++ (MVS2008) and I have problem like described in this thread:

[NVIDIA OpenGL driver lost connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638616/nvidia-opengl-driver-lost-connection)

what i want to ask is not for a solution, or why is this happenning (like in the posted thread), i want to ask if i can "catch" this error and do something before the application crushes, like an output log with some relevant information of the application state.

The error occurs every now and then while running the application without clear causes, therefore i would like such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Windows versions put a number of hard constraints on the responsiveness of applications. If a process spends too much time in a graphics operation driver call *or* takes too long to fetch events from Windows a watchdog triggers and Windows assumes that the process got stuck in an infinite loop *or* violates the responsivenes demands and may "do" something about it.

Try what happens if you break down a single `glDraw…` call into a number of smaller batches. In general you want to minimize the number of `glDraw…` calls, but if a single `glDraw…` call takes more than 10ms or so to complete, you're far beyond OpenGL overhead territory anyway.

Note that due to the asynchronous nature of OpenGL that watchdog may bark in a OpenGL finishing call `glFinish` or `SwapBuffers`. In that case it may help to help to add `glFlush` commands between the draw batches. If that doesn't help try `glFinish` (which will have a performance impact). If that doesn't help, too. Create an auxiliary OpenGL context in a separate thread that renders to a texture using a FBO and have the main thread display only the contents of this intermediary texture. And if that doesn't help, create the auxiliary context on a PBuffer instead on the same window as your main context.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.
Thing is, I am aware why this error occurs and how i can force the application reproduce it but i would like a way to return the application to a valid state after this error occurs